# Не работает логин через псевдоним в roundcube

Tags: php, linux, email, roundcube

Создаю в ISP Manager новый почтовый ящик для roundcube - user@domain.ru
И несколько псевдонимов для него - user0, user1. 
Почта, отправленная на user0@domain.ru успешно доходит на ящик user@domain.ru, т.е. псевдоним создан успешно.

В конфигах(в конфиге и в дефолте) включил логин через псевдонимы

```
// Enables possibility to log in using email address from user identities 
$config['user_aliases'] = true;
```

Тем не менее, попытка входа с логином user0@domain.ru и паролем от user@domain.ru не работает.

MTA Postfix

UPD:
Версия раундкуба 1.0.8, оказалось там прямая настройка логина через эллиасы отключена. 
Попытался воткнуть костыль [через плагин virtuser_query](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/pull/74), наверняка что-то сделал не так:
0.Поставил сам плагин, в раундкубе от отображается как установленный
1.Докинул в config.ini строчку

`$rcmail_config['virtuser_query'] = array('alias' => "SELECT username FROM users WHERE alias = '%u'");`

не помогло,пробовал

`$rcmail_config['virtuser_query'] = array('email' => '', 'user' => '', 'host' => '', 'alias' => "SELECT username FROM users WHERE alias = '%u'");
$config['virtuser_query'] = array('alias' => "SELECT username FROM users WHERE alias = '%u'");`

не помогло. Заменял %u на %m, безрезультатно.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с версии 0.9.1, roundcube больше не поддерживает авторизацию через alias.
Есть обходное решение - воспользоваться механизмом авторизации по алиасу из более ранних версий. Нужно внести изменения в файл

> plugins/virtuser_query/virtuser_query.php

Подробно здесь: https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/pull/74 (Вкладка files changed)

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Плагин поставил, раундкуб уверяет что плагин подключен. Код, отвечающий за аллиасы есть в теле плагина.
Докинул в config.ini строчку 

`$rcmail_config['virtuser_query'] = array('alias' => "SELECT username FROM users WHERE alias = '%u'");`
не помогло,
пробовал


`$rcmail_config['virtuser_query'] = array('email' => '', 'user' => '', 'host' => '', 'alias' => "SELECT username FROM users WHERE alias = '%u'");
$config['virtuser_query'] = array('alias' => "SELECT username FROM users WHERE alias = '%u'");`
не помогло. Заменял %u на %m, безрезультатно.

Comment: Обновил вопрос чтобы была сразу видна история всего балета. 
Перезагрузил сервер, может какие-то специфические параметры ещё в конфиге писать надо? Полезу в sql, может там что-то не находит, но слабо в это верю